# Using Federated Identities to create user in User Pool AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

i am using AWS Cognito to manage my app Sign In and Log In, on this way i authenticate my user against the user pool and obtain the jwt tokens (id token, access token and refresh token), i am using the id token to authenticate my app against the backend.

Now i want to integrate my app to make Sign in and Log in with Facebook, Gmail and others, as far as i know i should use the AWS Federated Identities, but i dont know how can i create my user in the user pool using the Facebook Login (p.eg) and obtain the tokens, may someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to federate identities into AWS is by using AWS Cognito Federated Identity as you mentioned. Your user pool can be configured as an identity provider for your identity pool, similar to Facebook, and Google. So all these options function as identity providers for your identity pool in order to federate identities into AWS.

Comment: How can i make aws generate the id and access token for me when i use Facebook FI ? I am sending the tokens to my own api backend and then i validate if the user is really logged in the app.

Comment: You cannot federate users into user pools at this point. However, we have heard this requirement in the past and are working on a solution to federate users into user pools using social providers. As I mentioned above, you can federate users into AWS using Cognito Federated Identities and obtain AWS credentials using Facebook, Google, User Pools, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to make my users log in the app using Facebook or other FI and then validate in my backend if the user making a request is actually logged in?